# Handling form submissions in WordPress for Visual Form Builder

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, forms, http-post

One of my WordPress website is using [Visual Form Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/) (free version) plugin for form submission. I have to inject some custom code while posting form data. Current version of Visual Form Builder only allows to set rules via admin panel.

Currently I am trying to achieve it using `admin-post.php` as explained in [this article](http://www.adaptiveweb.com.au/handle-post-and-get-requests-in-wordpress-using-admin-post-php/), but I am not able to get any data in `$_POST` array in `function.php`. Also I need to know which value come in place of `"process_form"` as I can't find any action in Visual form builder. Here is the code

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_process_form', 'process_form_data' );
add_action( 'admin_post_process_form', 'process_form_data' );
function process_form_data() {
  // form processing code here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://docs.vfbpro.com/category/49-hooks?

You can either override the full handling by setting the form action to a custom php file 
with **vfbp_form_action** or add some handlers after mailing or submission. If i get any more detailed code to do so I'll update. The documentation on this isn't very detailed.